# Multiple PagedList's in View: Keeping track of each list's current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, pagedlist

I'm hoping Troy Goode or someone else who has done the same thing can help out here. I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC.

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 app with a View where I have implemented two PagedList controls, each displaying a different source of information.

Does the PagedList control provide a means of tracking the current page number of other PagedLists on the View? So for example, if I had:

```
PagedList1 (currently on page 1 of 10)
PagedList2 (currently on page 4 of 10)
```

and I changed the page on PagedList1, PagedList2 would remain on page 4 after the View reloads.

I have considered using Session variables but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out a way.

**Model**:

```
public class ChequeSearch
{
    //Search criteria
    [DisplayName("Draft Number")]
    public string DraftNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Payee")]
    public string Payee { get; set; }

    //Search results
    public int? SearchResults1Page { get; set; }
    public int? SearchResults2Page { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Cheque> SearchResults1 { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Cheque> SearchResults2 { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
}
```

**View**:

Under search result table 1:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults1,
        page => Url.Action("Search", new RouteValueDictionary() {
            { "SearchResults1Page", page },
            { "SearchResults2Page", Model.SearchResults2Page },
            { "DraftNumber", Model.DraftNumber },
            { "Payee", Model.Payee }
        }),
        PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
```

Under search result table 2:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults2,
        page => Url.Action("Search", new RouteValueDictionary() {
            { "SearchResults2Page", page },
            { "SearchResults1Page", Model.SearchResults1Page },
            { "DraftNumber", Model.DraftNumber },
            { "Payee", Model.Payee }
        }),
        PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
```

Thanks for looking.